# Setting or plugin for showing submenus horizontally under the main menu, and keep them after selection

Tags: menus, pages

My blog's page hierarchy is as follows:

```
- Home
- About
- Movies
- - General
- - All Movies 
- - Rules
```

Right now, I have a horizontal menu showing `Home | About | Movies`, and if I hover Movies I get:

```
Home | About | >Movies<
     |       |  General
     |       |  All Movies
     |       |  Rules
```

When I choose, for example, `General`, the menu returns to `Home | About | Movies`. What I'd like is for the drop down to be horizontal as follows:

```
Home | About | >Movies<
General | All Movies | Rules
```

And that if I select one of the submenu pages, the submenu will stay there with a selection marked. So for example, if I click on `All Movies`, the menu will appear as follows (The "<" signs are for illustrating the selection, not to be used literally):

```
Home | About | >Movies<
General | >All Movies< | Rules
```

Is there a setting or a plugin that can help me achieve that?

For reference, my site is at http://roee.co

Answer (score 1):

Roee, there's no particular setting or plugin to do that kind of stuff, it's all about how your theme is designed and developed. You might be able to achieve this using some custom CSS if you're good enough with that. Basically what you have to do is find out the `:hover` state of a particular menu and apply the same rules to when the entry has got the `current_page_item` class, which WordPress appends when using `wp_nav_menu()`.

Comment: As an addition: The magic happens (mostly) with `float: left; clear: none;`.